# psql stopped printing SQL errors. How can I make it print errors again?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm using psql (version 14.3) to connect to remote postgres db (server version 12.11).

Some time ago my psql (in interactive mode) stopped displaying errors resulting from invalid SQL I sometimes enter as in this example:

```
mydb=> SELECT * FROM tabledoesntexist;
mydb=>
```

I found out I can print the error like this:

```
mydb=> \echo :LAST_ERROR_MESSAGE
relation "tabledoesnexist" does not exist
mydb=>
```

But this is annoying.
Is there something I can do to let the error be printed automatically right after query is executed? I remember it worked liked this some time ago, but then it stopped working at some point.

What I tried (but it didn't help)

```
\set VERBOSITY verbose
\echo :QUIET (the result is off)
checked there are no suspicious options being set in my ~/.psqlrc
```

Comment: I suspect that you redirected standard error of the `psql` command.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thank you so much for bringing me on the right track.
I was indeed starting psql from a shell script, "accidentally" discarding its stderr :facepalm: